# high performance buffers in objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, collections, buffer

I'm wondering what the most applicable kind of buffer implementation is for audio data in objective-c. I'm working with audio data on the iPhone, where I do some direct data manipulation/DSP of the audio data while recording or playing, so performance matters. I do iPhone development since some months now. Currently I'm dealing with c-arrays of element type SInt16 or Float32, but I'm looking for something better.

AFAIK, the performance of pointer-iterated c-arrays is unbeatable in an objective-c environment. However, pointer arithmetic and c-arrays are error prone. You always have to make sure that you do not access the arrays out of their bounds. You will not get a runtime error immediately if you do. And you have to make sure manually that you alloc and dealloc the arrays correctly.

Thus, I'm looking for alternatives. What high performance alternatives are there? Is there anything in objective-c similar to the c++ style std::vector?

With similar I mean:

- good performance

  - iteratable with pointer-/iterator-based loop
  - no overhead of boxing/unboxing basic data types like Float32 or SInt16 into objective-c objects (btw, what's the correct word for 'basic data types' in objective-c?)
- bounds-checking
- possibility to copy/read/write chunks of other lists or arrays into and out of my searched-for list implementation
- memory management included

I've searched and read quite a bit and of course `NSData` and `NSMutableArray` are among the mentioned solutions. However don't they double processing cost because of the overhead for the boxing/unboxing of basic data types? That the code looks outright ugly like a simple 'set'-operation becoming some dinosaur named `replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:` isn't of my concern, but still it subtly makes me think that this class is not made for me.

Comment: What's wrong with std::vector? You *can* use C++ code on iOS. Also, all of the things you mention result in overhead. Besides all Core Audio APIs will work on C arrays.

Comment: Yeah, if you want std::vector, just rename your implementation file to .mm and go forth and prosper.

Comment: And indeed, as far as I know, almost everyone doing iOS audio development (as indeed, audio development on pretty much every other platform) uses C++ too.   This includes almost all of Apple's example apps.

Comment: Also, not to be snarky and unhelpful, but C arrays and pointer arithmetic aren't error prone -- programmers are. The burden is always on the programmer to "get it right" regardless of the data structure being used.

Comment: Obvious caveat using `std::vector` is that `operator[]` *isn't* bounds checked, but consequently fast.  You'd want to use the `at()` method for that.

Comment: Bugger. For some reason I haven't been thinking about the C++/.mm alternative. Sometimes you just need someone to ask you "why don't you use the obvious solution?". Also thanks for the other helpful comments and answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The containers provided in the `Foundation` framework have little to offer for audio processing, being on the whole rather heavy-weight, nor providing extrinsic iterators.

Furthermore, none of the audio APIs in iOS or MacOSX that interact with buffers of samples are Objective-C - based, or take any parameters of Foundation framework containers.

Most likely, you would want to make use of the Accelerate Framework for DSP operations, and its APIs all work on arrays of `float`s or `int16`s.

Whilst all of the APIs are C-style,  C++ and STL is the obvious weapon of choice for your requirements, and interworks cleanly with the rest of an application in the guise of Objective-C++.  STL frequently compiles down to code which is about as efficient as hand-crafted C.

To memory-manage your buffers, perhaps use `std::array` - if you want bounds checking or `std::shared_ptr` or `std::unique_ptr` with a custom deleter if you're not worried.

Places where an `iterator` is expected - for instance algorithm functions in `<algorithm>` - can usually also take pointers to basic types - such as your sample buffers.

Answer (score 3):

`NSMutableData` hits one of your requirements in that it brings Objective-C memory management semantics to plain C buffers.  You can do something like this:

```
NSMutableData* data = [NSMutableData dataWithLength: sizeof(Float32) * numberOfFloats];
Float32* cFloatArray = (Float32*)[data mutableBytes];
```

And you can then treat `cFloatArray` as a standard C array and use pointer iteration. When the `NSMutableData` object is dealloc'ed the memory backing it will be freed.  It doesn't give you bounds checking, but it delivers memory management help while preserving the performance of C arrays.

Also, if you want some help from the tools in ironing out bounds-checking issues read up on Xcode's  Malloc Scribble, Malloc Guard Edges and Guard Malloc options.  These will make the runtime *much* more sensitive to bounds problems.  Not useful in production, but can be helpful in ironing out issues during development.